# MarkMap Toolbar renders but doesn't attach to the embedded script

Tags: javascript, markdown, mindmap

I have a simple static HTML page using MarkMap. I link to two required libraries to enable the functionality. I don't quite know why I can render the mindmap AND the default Toolbar, but no clicks on the toolbar perform the corresponding actions (e.g., Zoom In, Zoom Out, Recenter, etc.).  Any help is greatly appreciated.

`Code` and Stackblitz link follow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Markmap</title>
    <style>
      svg.markmap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-autoloader@0.16"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-toolbar@0.16.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="mm" class="markmap">
        <script type="text/template">
          ---
          markmap:
            maxWidth: 300
            colorFreezeLevel: 2
          ---

          # markmap

          ## Links

          - <https://markmap.js.org/>
          - [GitHub](https://github.com/markmap/markmap)

          ## Related

          - [coc-markmap](https://github.com/markmap/coc-markmap)
          - [gatsby-remark-markmap](https://github.com/markmap/gatsby-remark-markmap)

          ## Features
          - links
          - **inline** ~~text~~ *styles*
          - multiline
            text
          - `inline code`
          - Katex - $x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}$
          - This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line.
        </script>
        <script>
          const { markmap } = window;
          const { Toolbar } = markmap;

          const { el } = Toolbar.create(mm);
          el.style.position = 'absolute';
          el.style.bottom = '0.5rem';
          el.style.right = '0.5rem';

          // `container` could be the element that contains both the markmap and the toolbar
          container.append(el);
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[StackBlitz working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/markmap-autoloader-hqtg4z?file=index.html)